# getColumnCount() won't return anything higher than 7

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I've been following along a tutorial on Youtube and everything works. I tried to make modifications on my own which is my question right now. When I use `getColumnCount()` to return 7, it works. Anything higher than that gets me a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:7`

Here's the video in the specific time:
https://youtu.be/OxaSi3nSl3I?t=15233

Here's my code (refer to getColumnCount):

```
package view;

import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

import model.Product;

public class ProductTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<Product> db;

    private String[] colNames = {"ID", "Product", "Unit Price", "Quantity", "Service", "TIN", "TIN Number "};

    public ProductTableModel() {

    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {

        return colNames[column];
    }


    public void setData(List<Product> db) {
        this.db = db;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 7;
    }


    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return db.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        Product product = db.get(row);

        switch(col) {
        case 0:
            return product.getId();
        case 1:
            return product.getProdName();
        case 2:
            return product.getUnitPrice();
        case 3:
            return product.getqtyCategory();
        case 4:
            return product.getDpCat();
        case 5:
            return product.isHasTin();
        case 6:
            return product.getTinNum();

        }
return null;
    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated :D

Comment: In your example, `getColumnCount` is tied to the `colNames` array.  So if you want more columns, you need to add more elements to that array.  `getColumnCount` really should return `colNames.length`, that way when you change it, you don't have to remember to update the method

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Thank you very much @MadProgrammer! I understand now and it worked.